# Error vis.min.js al cargar un gráfico

Tags: javascript, jquery

El error es el siguiente:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot add item: item with id 14 already exists
at n._addItem (vis.min.js:27)
at n.add (vis.min.js:27)
at Object.success (base.js:62)
at fire (jquery-3.1.1.js:3305)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.js:3435)
at done (jquery-3.1.1.js:9242)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.js:9484)
```

El id del elemento que da el error cambia, no es todo el rato el mismo, y el error no se da siempre si no que se da de vez en cuando.

¿Alguien tiene alguna solución o simplemente es un bug del vis.min.js?

Aquí dejo la parte de código donde me da el error:

```
function alerts_timeline(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/draw/alerts_timeline/",
        data: { 
            "duracion": "day",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var items = new vis.DataSet();
            for (i=0; i < data.alertas.length; i++) {
                items.add(data.alertas[i]);
            }
            var options = data.opciones
            var container = document.getElementById('alert_timeline');
            timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, null, options);
            timeline.setItems(items);

        }
    });
}
```

No se si ayuda pero es una parte de código que desarrolló un compañero con unos tutoriales.

Comment: Hola, no tengo claro que es el `vis.min.js` pero el error parece lo suficientemente descriptivo. Tienes un elemento con un id repetido. **El id 14 ya existe** y `vis.min.js` tiene un problema con ello. Igual podrías revisar a ver si tienes ids repetidos o ese problema se puede producir.

Comment: @lois6b El problema es que el archivo vis.min.js es una librería y está sin sangriar ni nada, es ilegible...

Comment: @frikinside Se que el error es claro, lo que no tengo tan claro es como se produce y mucho menos como evitarlo...

Comment: @frikinside Si tu mismo que tienes el código no te es claro, menos nosotros que no tenemos tu código hermano.

Comment: No tengo experiencia con esa librería en concreto, pero me imagino (de ahí que ponga un comentario y no una respuesta) que cuando vas añadiendo elementos para mostrar se les asigne un identificador. Mi supuesto es que ese id del elemento está repetido y por eso arroja ese error. Sería posible que cuando cargues elementos para mostrar con la librería se le asigne un id duplicado?

Comment: Es que el código es una librería y no está con sangría ni separado ni nada, es un bloque de letras y números... @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver

Comment: Podría ser si, como comento, es un bug de la librería @frikinside . Pregunto sobre este error por si alguien está o ha estado en mi misma situación.

Comment: Es que no tengo claro que el error sea de la librería y estoy jugando con supuestos. Igual una forma de evitar los supuestos y así todos lo tenemos más claro, sería si pudieras proporcionarnos el código con el que cargas/alimentas los datos a la librería para que te pinte el gráfico, a ver si ahí podemos intuir un posible error.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver creo que te liaste al mencionar, el código no es mio jeje

Comment: @frikinside ahí he dejado la parte de código en la que salta el error, como pongo ahí, ese código es de un compañero que siguió unos tutos.... De verdad siento no poder aportar más... y gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando cargas el data set en el código proporcionado, rellenas la información en base a un json que devuelve la petición ajax.

```
items.add(data.alertas[i]);
```

El data set, espera que los datos que le ofreces tengan un formato parecido a este:

```
{id: 1, content: 'item 1', start: '2014-04-20'}
```

Donde le especificas un `id`. Si ese `id` se encuentra repetido, la librería falla, por que debería de ser único.

Lo suyo sería que en el método del servidor donde se generan las alertas que recibes, se validase que no contiene un id repetido, no obstante, si quieres comprobarlo por JavaScript puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
for (i=0; i < data.alertas.length; i++) {
    if(items.getIds().indexOf(data.alertas[i].id) == -1) {
        items.add(data.alertas[i]);
    }
}
```

De esa forma te aseguras que `items` no contenga un elemento con ids repetidos.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, cuando vuelva a ello lo pruebo y comento a ver que tal

Comment: He estado mirando, y hay una parte de una función de un archivo de python en la que tengo un diccionario con exactamente esa estructura, ¿la validación podría hacerla perfectamente ahí no?

Comment: No veo por que no, pero en ese caso la validación se tendría que hacer en `Python`.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, ya comentaré que tal va.